CSS files not loading for Next.js app in standalone mode
I'm currently encountering an issue with my Next.js app running in standalone mode on an EC2 instance with Apache as the web server.
The issue I'm facing is that while I can access the Next.js homepage, the CSS files are not being loaded, resulting in an unstyled page. I've ensured that the CSS file paths are correct in my Next.js.
The Next.js app is running in standalone mode with PM2 (pm2 start .next/standalone/server.js).
conf file in apache
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/example/nextjs-app
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyVia Full
        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>
        
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>


Do i have to configure something related to static files in apache ?

Did you remember to manually copy the public and/or .next/static folders to the final standalone/public and standalone/.next/static folders? (standalone mode doesn't do this for you). See the paragraph above the "good to know" box from their docs. I just use an NPM script: "postbuild": "cp -R public .next/standalone && cp -R .next/static .next/standalone/.next".
